# How to append a list selectively?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, rfid

I'm receiving my messages via a RFID reader. What I am trying to do is to remove duplicates and only append to a list following two conditions:

1. If their ID (`epc` in this case) is unique and, *(done)*
2. The `datetime` is after a 5 minutes interval (so I can keep track of the same tag is still being read by the RFID reader every 5 mins)

   ```
   import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
   import json

   testlist = []       

   def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
       payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
       line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
       epc =  line[1]
       datetime = payloadjson['datetime']
       # datetime is in this string format '2016-04-06 03:21:17'

       payload = {'datetime': datetime, 'epc': epc[11:35]}

       # this if-statement satisfy condition 1
       if payload not in testlist:
           testlist.append(payload)
           for each in teslist:
               print (each)

   test = mqtt.Client(protocol = mqtt.MQTTv31)
   test.connect(host=_host, port=1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
   test.on_connect = on_connect
   test.on_message = on_message
   test.loop_forever()
   ```

How can I achieve condition 2?

***UPDATE***
I apologize for the unclear goal that I'm trying to achieve

My desired output will look something like this:

```
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
...
...
# 5 minutes later
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:26:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:26:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
...
...
# Another 5 minutes later
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:21:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:26:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:26:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:31:17', 'epc': 00000001} # from Tag A
{'datetime': 2016-04-06 03:31:18', 'epc': 00000002} # from Tag B
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear.  Presuming you want to update testlist if it is a new epc, or if it has been > 5 minutes since the last update to the epc.  A `dict()` would work well in this case.  Use the `datetime` module from the standard library to compute differences in dates or times.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import datetime as dt

TIMELIMIT = dt.timedelta(minutes=5)

testlist = {}       ## <<-- changed this to a dict()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]

    # this converts the time stamp string to something python can
    # use in date / time calculations
    when = dt.datetime.strptime(payloadjson['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    if epc not in testlist or when - testlist[epc] > TIMELIMIT:
        testlist[epc] = when

        for epc, when in teslist.items():
            print (epc, when)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! May I ask what's the difference between `testlist['epc']` vs `testlist[epc]`? To my current understanding, the former simply means using `epc` as key for dict `testlist`, how about the latter? What's the 'magic' behind?

Comment: `'epc'` is a string literal consisting of the three characters `e`, `p`, and `c`.  `testlist['epc']` is using that literal string as the key.  In contrast, `epc` is a variable name and can be bound to any value.  For example, `epc = 42` binds the name `epc` to the value `42`.  `testlist[epc]` uses the value bound to the name `epc` as the key.

Answer (score 2):

This can probably be an easier approach:

```
class EPC(object):
    def __init__(self, epc, date):
        self.epc = epc
        self.datetime = date
    def __eq__(self, other):
        difference = datetime.strptime(self.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(other.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return self.epc == other.epc and timedelta(minutes=-5) < difference < timedelta(minutes=5)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        difference = datetime.strptime(self.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(other.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return self.epc != other.epc or (self.epc == other.epc and (difference > timedelta(minutes=5) or difference < timedelta(minutes=-5))) 

payload = EPC(date, epc[11:35])
if payload not in test_list:
    test_list.append(payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to wonder if the `epc` values can alternate back and forth. That is, would it be possible for epc value 'A' to appear, then epc value 'B', then epc value 'A' once again? (Or possibly A, B, C, etc.?)

If the assumption is that there will only be one tag, then just look at the most recent entry:

```
last_tag = testlist[-1]
last_dt = last_tag['datetime']
```

Now you can compare the current `datetime` with the previous value to see if it fits in your window.

Please be aware, though, that putting the datetime code in the has won't actually work for your existing code, since the datetime keeps changing, so `payload not in testlist` will always be true unless you get two RFID reads on the exact same second.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to address your problem:

1. For ID uniqueness, you need to check for the `epc` field only, not the whole `payload` object, since the `payload` object includes the `datetime`. You can use a `set` to store all seen IDs.
2. For checking time, use `datetime` and `timedelta` objects to compare time

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
06 Apr 2016
To answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440618/
"""

# Import statements

# import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import datetime as dt

testlist = []
seen_ids = set()  # The set of seen IDs
five_minutes = dt.timedelta(minutes=5)  # The five minutes differences

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]
    datetime = payloadjson['datetime']
    # datetime is in this string format '2016-04-06 03:21:17'

    # Convert the string into datetime object
    datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    payload = {'datetime': datetime, 'epc': epc[11:35]}

    # this if-statement satisfy condition 1
    if payload['epc'] not in seen_ids:  # Need to use another set
        should_add = True               # The flag whether to add
        if len(testlist) > 0:
            last_payload = testlist[-1]
            diff = payload['datetime'] - last_payload['datetime']
            if diff < five_minutes:     # If the newer one is less than five minutes, do not add
                should_add = False
        if should_add:
            seen_ids.add(payload['epc'])    # Mark as seen
            testlist.append(payload)
            print ('Content of testlist now:')
            for each in testlist:
                print (each)

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, payload):
        self.payload = payload

def main():
    test_cases = []
    for i in range(10):
        payload = '{{"value":",{}","datetime":"2016-04-06 03:{:02d}:17"}}'.format('0'*34+str(i), i)
        test_case = Message(payload)
        test_cases.append(test_case)
    for test_case in test_cases:
        on_message(None, None, test_case)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Will print:

```
Content of testlist now:
{'epc': u'000000000000000000000000', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 3, 0, 17)}
Content of testlist now:
{'epc': u'000000000000000000000000', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 3, 0, 17)}
{'epc': u'000000000000000000000005', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 3, 5, 17)}
```